# Crawl through all folders and files in a directory

Tags: python, csv

I have a directory structures as follows:

```
.
├── 0_0_a_example
│   ├── ab.csv
│   └── cd.csv
├── 0_1_b_example
│   ├── ab.csv
│   └── cd.csv
├── 1_0_c_example
│   ├── ab.csv
│   └── cd.csv
└── 1_1_d_example
    ├── ab.csv
    └── cd.csv
```

I want to write a Python script to plot a 2x2 graph with each first file in each subdirectory (then each second file).

I intentionally named each subdirectory beginning with `ixj` so it makes it easier to iterate (I don't care about the rest of the name). I'm looking at other answers that use `glob` and `os`, but the solutions I found are to read the files directly, not subdirectories and files.

```py
import glob

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        subdir = glob.glob(f'{i}_{j}_*')
        print(subdir)
        file = os.listdir(subdir[0])[0]
        print(file)
```

Is there an easier way to do this? (or a more Pyhtonic way to do this)

Also, my solution sometimes prints the file `cd.csv` as first index.

Comment: i realize you said you've looked into ```os```, but have you tried ```os.walk()``` specifically? i'm pretty sure it covers directories as well as subdirectories, with the ability to crawl the directories from top down or bottom up.

Comment: I haven't. Will look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use walk().

```
import os
for directory, subdirlist, filelist in os.walk('/path/root/'):
   print(directory)
   for f in filelist:
       print('\t' + f)
```

[documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to traverse all the files and subdirectories in the current directory then a simple depth-first or breadth-first search would do

```
import os
import sys 

# BFS
dir_to_explore = sys.argv[1] # Absolute path to the directory you want to crawl
print(f"Crawling {dir_to_explore}...")
q = os.listdir(dir_to_explore)
current_path = dir_to_explore
all_files = []

while q:
    current_file_or_dir = os.path.join(current_path, q.pop(0))
    all_files.append(current_file_or_dir)
    if os.path.isdir(current_file_or_dir): 
        files_and_dirs = list(map(lambda x:os.path.join(current_file_or_dir,x) ,os.listdir(current_file_or_dir)))
        q.extend(files_and_dirs)

for i in all_files:
    print(i)
```

The `all_files` list will contain absolute paths to all files and subdirectories so you can filter the list to grab the CSV files and then read them directly

Answer (score 1):

I think that's pretty good

You can sort files before print

```
#sort by name
files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.basename(x))
```